# Should code snippets cover edge cases?

Tags: discussion, answers

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564726/how-to-elegantly-check-if-any-field-has-a-longer-value-between-two-objects-in-js), for example, asks:

> How to elegantly check if any field has a longer value between two objects in JS?

and gives the following input:

```
item1 = {a:[1], b:[2], c:[3]}
item2 = {a:[1], b:[2], c:[3,4]}
```

Don't get me wrong: I think the answers posted there are stellar. However, they don't cover the edge case where some key might not contain an Array.

Is that a problem? Are answers expected to provide code snippets that cover every edge case?

For what it's worth, I think that it's out of scope to cover edge-cases in answers. Instead, the asker should be responsible for adapting the provided code to production-level quality.

Comment: No, it's not expected that you build someone's entire application for them, write all the unit tests, account for all the edge cases, or whatever else. Surely you know this already. It is rather common sense. Are you seeking to create a canonical reference that you can point people to, or genuinely wondering if this is necessary?

Comment: @CodyGray Genuinely wondering where the line is drawn; I've sometimes had comments on my answers of the type `What if x doesnt contain value y`. I'm guessing from your comment you mean only the immediate problem as stated.

Comment: Well, naturally the more detailed and thorough the answer is, the better the answer is. But at the same time, it isn't expected that you spoon-feed people. It's just expected that you answer the question. So, unless the question is about those corner cases, you can still have a perfectly valid answer without addressing them.

Comment: On second thought, I think it's quite obvious that the answer is "it depends". I'll vote to close my Q as opinion-based.

Comment: I can't really judge that; I don't speak Javascript,and the linked Q&A doesn't really make much sense to me. This is a perfectly valid Meta question, though, so don't feel like you have to close it. It's okay to have opinion-based discussion on Meta, as long as it is opinions about Stack Overflow.

Comment: Answers should *at least* specify what preconditions they require if there are conditions not explicitly stated by the asker.

Comment: And I voted to close that question when it was asked since it is not really a good question. "How to elegantly check" is a personal opinion on what is elegant  and OP did not give a solution that was "not elegant".

Comment: unless it's a bounty, I wouldn't care too much. one can still leave a comment hinting for that... such edge-case often only become obvious when writing it - but might not had been asked for.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Is it expected? No. You may do so, but such considerations are not all equally useful.

Since you're (usually) not writing the entire application yourself, at some point you have to expect the user to use the code properly. If you have a short function that uses a parameter as an array, then it would be obvious to most programmers that the value has to be an array. You could call that out explicitly, but because most programmers can see that, it's about as useful as a comment explaining that `a + b` adds `a` and `b`.

That being said, there are times when such information is really valuable. If the OP mentioned that some value is being provided by code outside of their control, then a discussion of sanitizing inputs is not unreasonable. And if the data is user provided and could pose a security concern, then *definitely* bring up the importance of making sure the input is properly sanitized.

Overall, make sure that such discussions add value to the answer.

Comment: Note, this is programming defensively.

Answer (score 2):

> However, they don't cover the edge case where some key might not contain an Array.

This presupposes that that actually counts as an "edge case". One may ask what the result should be in that case, and one may answer (for example) that the case will be explicitly checked for in advance, or cannot arise by previous construction of the code.

In general, input specifications should show enough examples, and have enough detail in those examples, to make it clear what the code should do for every valid input. The text of the question, meanwhile, should define valid input.

It is perfectly reasonable to *restrict* the question to considering objects where every key is known to hold an array, given that the problem statement is naturally phrased in terms of comparing array lengths. The question should state such a restriction implicitly.

If you think a problem is *underspecified within its explicit restrictions*, then implicitly you think the question is unclear. So do the usual things: consider any combination of downvoting, voting or flagging to close as needing details or clarity, and commenting to explain the specific issue. That is: propose an example input in the comments where you can't discern what OP thinks the output should be, and ask about the desired output and reasoning behind it.

Similarly if the explicitly stated, desired output seems strange or wrong: comment to say that, according to your understanding of the rest of the question, you think the output for X should be Z (rather than OP's stated Y), and ask why that is wrong.